# Chrome Extension - Pulsing / Glowing extension logo

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Client asked me to make the extension logo glow / pulse as an alert. I am talking about the small logo among other extension logos.

Is it actually possible to do something like that? If so what would be the steps?

Comment: If you mean the toolbar icon, see [google chrome extension canvas icon](//stackoverflow.com/q/29056704)

Comment: @wOxxOm That should do it, thanks a lot.